# Chart reporting in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I am using SQL Server Reporting to display data using a chart. How do I create my dataset so that the graph displays one line for males & one line for females.

Thanks

Beth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean two lines as in

- one per x or y axis
- one per data series
- This stupid thing won't allow me to comment so I'm wasting space with an answer

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is to separate the males and females into different data series. You can go this in the chart properties, as long as you have enough information in your data set.

If your data set looks something like this:

```
+-----------+-----+-------+
| Date      | Sex | Count |
+-----------+-----+-------+
| 2009-01-1 | M   | 124   |
+-----------+-----+-------+
| 2009-01-1 | F   | 78    |
+-----------+-----+-------+
| 2009-01-2 | M   | 95    |
+-----------+-----+-------+
| 2009-01-2 | F   | 101   |
+-----------+-----+-------+
```

Then if you have the Date as the X-Axis variable, Count as the Y-Axis, and add the Sex as the Series Grouping, the it should automatically split them into two graph lines, and add a Legend etc.